# C++ : Vector assignment error

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/ I understand that we can use the '=' operator for assignment of vectors. But running the following code, I get an error. What is going wrong?

**Code:**

```
 void checkFunction(map<string, vector<string> > foo){
     vector<string> bar;     
     bar = foo.find("ABC");
     }
```

**Error :**

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘bar = foo.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::find [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>, _Tp = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >, key_type = std::basic_string<char>](((const std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::key_type&)(& std::basic_string<char>(((const char*)"PAR"), ((const std::allocator<char>&)((const std::allocator<char>*)(& std::allocator<char>())))))))’

std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >]
std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&&) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >]
std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::initializer_list<_CharT>) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >]
```

Comment: @LotharKrause: Yeah, but why does this error crop up then?

Comment: Because `map::find` gives you an iterator which is dereferenced to pair<Key,Value>, according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `map::find` method returns an iterator pointing at the element you search for (stored in a `std::pair` containing the key as `first` and value as `second`).

To access the vector pointed at by the iterator, you need to dereference it and fetch the `second` element of the pair.

```
void checkFunction(map<string, vector<string> > foo){
    typedef map<string, vector<string> > map_t;

    map_t::const_iterator i = foo.find("ABC");
    if (i == foo.end()) {
        // element not found!
    }

    vector<string> bar(i->second);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It still doesn't work!? Getting a similar error again.

Comment: operator[] returns a reference to the vector, so this would work:
bar = foo["ABC"];

Comment: The iterator dereferences to a std::pair, it isn't one itself. Also, don't use operator[] unless you're ok with an element being inserted if the key isn't found.

Comment: @Peter be careful that operator[] and find have a notable difference. [] will create a default element using the given key if the key in question is not originally found in the map, while find will return end() if the key is not found, leaving the map untouched.

Comment: @SirDarius Absolutely. If this needs t be avoided, const correct programming can be used. On a `const std::map`, only `find` is available and `operator[]` is not.